# Altair: Discrete/Binned Color Scheme for Heatmap

Tags: colors, legend, heatmap, altair, binning

I am trying to create a heatmap where the color scale is discrete, not continuous. I would like to use 5 colors, so I don't think a conditional statement will work. I found this example on [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/g/altair-viz/c/KXjQwWuP9QE?pli=1), but it doesn't seem to be working completely. How can I fix it to get the actual heatmap to appear as expected?

```
   import altair as alt
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    
    np.random.seed(0)
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'x': np.random.randint(0, 5, 100),
        'y': np.random.randint(0, 5, 100),
        'z': np.random.rand(100)
    })
    
    alt.Chart(df).mark_rect().encode(
        x='x:O',
        y='y:O',
        color=alt.Color('mean(z)', bin=alt.Bin(maxbins=5))
    )
```

Expected Result:

[image]

Actual Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a `transform_aggregate` function might help.

```
alt.Chart(df).mark_rect().encode(
    x='x:O',
    y='y:O',
    color=alt.Color('mean_z', bin=alt.Bin(maxbins=5)),
).transform_aggregate(
    mean_z='mean(z)',
    groupby=["x","y"]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/scale.html#bin-ordinal, I think you are doing things correctly. Running your code on the latest development version of Altair give the expected result for me, so it might be a bug in previous versions. You can try installing the latest version directly from GitHub.

Related: [Altair Color binned values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64905486/altair-color-binned-values?rq=1&answertab=trending#tab-top)